# Azure Application Gateway Multisite listener through Application Gateway Ingress Controller

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway

Hi I am looking for a way to create multisite listener type and provide hostnames of the sites when Application gateway is created by Application gateway ingress controller.

By default, AGIC creates listeners of type basic, which is not working correctly when more than one ingress with different hostnames are deployed in a AKS cluster.

Can anybody suggest required annotations to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Just ran a quick [green field deployment](https://azure.github.io/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/setup/install-new/) and it's working fine. AGIC is creating multiple basic listeners on port 80 and serving traffic to multiple hosts even though the portal interface is showing [errors](https://github.com/Azure/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/issues/966#issuecomment-668439315). Please make sure you creating the [Ingress](https://github.com/Azure/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/issues/919#issuecomment-646909772) and other k8s objects properly.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: name-virtual-host-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
spec:
  rules:
  - host: foo.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: aspnetapp
          servicePort: 80
  - host: bar.foo.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: nginx
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you suggest what annotations required (apart of ingress.class) on the ingress resource for this to work properly? Is     appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-hostname required for multi-site routing to work?

Comment: You just need multiple host entries as I have specified in the code snippet. The code above would respond to both `foo.bar.com` and `bar.foo.com`. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: I have these definitions in separate ingress resources. I guess that should not make any difference.

Comment: Correct. It should work either way. What error are you getting? It should work fine even if it's not configuring multi-site listener. Please see the github issue references I have added in my reply.